# Does list concatenation with the `+` operator always return a new `list` instance?

Tags: python

In Python, one can use the following to concatenate two lists into a **new** one:

```py
l1 = [0, 1, 2]
l2 = [3, 4, 5]
l3 = l1 + l2
```

I am looking for the language reference/documentation describing the `+` operation on two lists to be sure that a compliant Python implementation has to return a new list but can't find it. Said differently, does the Python language itself guarantee that list concatenation with the `+` operator always results in a new list?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt is there any place on the stack community to ask such questions ?

Comment: [``s + t`` the concatenation of ``s`` and ``t``](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi this does not explain what is happening truely : do I have a new object or not ?

Comment: I don't see a reason why there needs to be a place where you can ask about links to existing documentation. Locating Python docs isn't particularly difficult...

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt tbh I didn't know where to look for this information until it was linked in the comments. Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385479/when-is-a-resource-request-on-topic

Comment: @mkrieger1 I didn't know either. I also don't know many bytes a `double` takes in C. But give me 30 seconds on google and I know both.

Comment: @Tomerikoo yes I saw that, but list are not immutable.

Comment: @mkrieger1 That meta post is interesting because quite frankly this is *not* simple to find. So I would see merit in such a Q&A. It would help if the question would more clearly define what exactly it is looking for – the ``+`` operator is documented at several different place, and the comments indicate a very specific behaviour is actually the quesiton.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I added precision in the question

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt i actually opened a question for that because I was not able to find the link after searching carefully for it.

Comment: @ManuelSelva damn! dumb moment from my side... Indeed lists are mutable, but the idea is that the general conception is that `+` (`__add__`) returns a new object (even for mutable objects) while `+=` (`__iadd__`) usually mutates the left operand

Answer (score 2):

[answer for a previous version of question: "where to look for docs"]

[doc on +](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq)

In Python `+` and `+=` are executed by calling `__add__` and `__iadd__` methods.

Unfortunately `help([].__add__)` or `help(list.__add__)` won't provide any useful doc.

Comment: I don't see how that will help (did you check the output?)

Comment: "Help on method-wrapper object: ``__add__ = class method-wrapper(object)``" That does not look like the proper documentation.

Comment: Yes I tried that too before opening the question, and the `__add__ = class method-wrapper(object)` was not super helpful :) Also the link you provided in the answer is about `+=` and not `+` if I am correct

Comment: thank you, but still the link does not answer to my question (I edited it to make it more precise)

Comment: it does: Concatenating immutable sequences always results in a new object.

Comment: Not a full answer, but if you execute `s + t`, which list do you think *might* be mutated? Simpler to assume *neither*, and a new list is created.

Comment: @chepner I completely agree with what you said. But my question is that I want to see that written somewhere in the python documentation :)

Comment: @Manuel thanks for bringing this up, it happened to be actually funny, that it was so overlooked by all docs

Comment: @AndrewLyashko I am afraid we will not have an answer :(

Comment: Note that the documentation is not as comprehensive as it should be. If there is no explicit documentation that `list.__add__` returns a new `list` instance without modifying its arguments, that's a shortcoming of the documentation, not a suggestion that a Python implementation can mutate one of its arguments.

Answer (score 2):

The reference documentation does *not* explicitly guarantee that `:list + :list` results in a new list. However, it is implied by the `+=` augmented assignment being explicitly in-place if possible in contrast to the `+` operator.

> #### The Python Language Reference: [Augmented assignment statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements)
>
> An augmented assignment expression like `x += 1` can be rewritten as `x = x + 1` to achieve a similar, but not exactly equal effect. In the augmented version, `x` is only evaluated once. **Also, when possible, the actual operation is performed in-place, meaning that rather than creating a new object and assigning that to the target, the old object is modified instead.**

The Python reference implementation CPython explicitly [creates a new list on concatenation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b121a4a45ff4bab8812a9b26ceffe5ad642f5d5a/Objects/listobject.c#L534). Other compliant implementations can be expected to provide observably equivalent behaviour unless otherwise noted.

---

The [`list` type is documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) to "implement all of the [common](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) and [mutable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable) sequence operations". These only guarantee that `+=` extends mutable sequences inplace, and `+` creates a new object for *immutable* sequences.

> `s + t` | the concatenation of s and t | (6)
> (6) Concatenating immutable sequences always results in a new object. […]

> `s.extend(t)` or `s += t` | extends `s` with the contents of `t` (for the most part the same as `s[len(s):len(s)] = t`)