# What happens internally when concatenating two lists in Python?

Tags: python, list, cpython

When concatenating two lists,

```
a = [0......, 10000000]
b = [0......, 10000000]

a = a + b
```

does the Python runtime allocate a bigger array and loop through both arrays and put the elements of `a` and `b` into the bigger array?

Or does it loop through the elements of `b` and append them to `a` and resize as necessary?

I am interested in the CPython implementation.

Comment: Just FYI - https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#how-are-lists-implemented-in-cpython  about the list implementation.

Answer (score 4):

You can find out by looking at the `id` of `a` before and after concatenating `b`:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [4, 5, 6]
>>> id(a)
140025874463112
>>> a = a + b
>>> id(a)
140025874467144
```

Here, since the `id` is different, we see that the interpreter has created a new list and bound it to the name `a`. The old `a` list will be garbage collected eventually.

However, the behaviour can be different when using the augmented assignment operator `+=`:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [4, 5, 6]
>>> id(a)
140025844068296
>>> a += b
>>> id(a)
140025844068296
```

Here, since the `id` is the same, we see that the interpreter has reused the same list object `a` and appended the values of `b` to it.

For more detailed information, see these questions:

- [Why does += behave unexpectedly on lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/why-does-behave-unexpectedly-on-lists)
- [Does list concatenation with the `+` operator always return a new `list` instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64644671/does-list-concatenation-with-the-operator-always-return-a-new-list-instanc)

Answer (score 4):

In CPython, two lists are concatenated in [function `list_concat`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.0a4/Objects/listobject.c#L500).

You can see in the linked source code that that function allocates the space needed to fit both lists.

```
size = Py_SIZE(a) + Py_SIZE(b);
np = (PyListObject *) list_new_prealloc(size);
```

Then it copies the items from both lists to the new list.

```
for (i = 0; i < Py_SIZE(a); i++) {
    ...
}
...
for (i = 0; i < Py_SIZE(b); i++) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see the implementation in [listobject.c::list_concat](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c). Python will get the size of `a` and `b` and create a new list object of that size. It will then loop through the values of `a` and `b`, which are C pointers to python objects, increment their ref counts and add those pointers to the new list.

Answer (score 1):

It will create a new list with a shallow copy of the items in the first list, followed by a shallow copy of the items in the second list. The `+` operator calls the `object.__add__(self, other)` method. For example, for the expression `x + y`, where `x` is an instance of a class that has an `__add__()` method, `x.__add__(y)` is called. You can read more in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__).